# How to upgrade Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS to Xfce 4.16?

Tags: xfce, ubuntu-studio

I've found some repositories to upgrade Linux Mint to Xfce 4.16, but none about Ubuntu Studio. Can I use then? Is there an official way to do this upgrade?

Comment: It may have been easier if you'd provided the links to the repositories you have seen.  I've seen many references/questions about this on IRC (#xubuntu etc), but I didn't take much notice... (the PPA if provided may have allowed me to provide more, but I'm not searching irc logs without a search string)

Comment: Probably. I see no reason for the current desktop to interfere with a new desktop. . The dependencies needed will all resolve automatically (as long as you provide the correct repositories)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add special [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Exubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/staging) from “Xubuntu Developers” team named
Xubuntu QA Staging and install packages from it by executing commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Note: to revert the changes use `ppa-purge` by `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:xubuntu-dev/staging` .

Answer (score 1):

If you do this, prepare for possible instability:

- Random logout bug (startx shutdown) when removing indicator applet (normally changing various settings to your taste), or randomly during the next session. after that, without debugging, that user graphical UI session is done indefinitely.
- On unlock screen it is quite possible you will not be able to enter your unlock password, as the keyboard input and focus will be nonexisting (X input problem?) (only solution for me was to hard power off)

[initial bug report is up at XFCE gitlab under session](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/-/issues/502)

Just some thoughts on the problems experienced some time after  upgrading to Xfce 4.16